# Importing Parse exported JSON file to mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, parse-platform, relational-database, mongoimport

I have some files that exported from Parse database, I am trying to import these datas to my local mongodb with `mongoimport` command.

```
mongoimport --db dev --collection Organization <Organization.json
mongoimport --db dev --collection _User <_User.json
```

But i cant import `_Join:xxx.json` files properly to relational collections (**Classes**).

```
mongoimport --db dev --collection _User <_Join:organization:_User.json
```

this command puts new rows in user instead of creating relational column in `_User` collection.

**_Join:organization:_User.json** file contents

```
{ "result" : 
   [
    {
        "owningId": "zzfq8hNM3K",
        "relatedId": "Tg4P5UarAG"
    }
 ]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by  relational column iin _User collection ?